# Using temp memory for smart calculating

Tags: python

I have a code where I need to go through lines and sum up index x, if they have a matching index[0]. What would be the best solution to create this? I guess I could have defaultdict and if there is a match in index[0] it would add the values. Is there a way that I could read it line by line, and have the index[0] always at temp memory and if it matches next index[0] it would do the sum up?

This is what I have so far:

```
with open("test.txt") as f:
    dic = defaultdict(list)
    for line in f:
        spl =line.split("\t")
        if("Fam" in line):
            dic[spl[0]].append(spl[1:])
            a = float(spl[5])
            b = float(spl[6])
            sum = a * b
            output = str(sum)
            this = line.strip() + "\t"+output
            if("TK" in line): #I would like to start sum up after this. Read all lines that include "TK", check index[0] for matches, if match sum up.
```

edit. I'm doing this to sorted list.

Thanks in advance

edit2. Since people are having problems understanding me maybe some output would help.
Currently variable `this` prints:

```
Fam_c1_1        F       Extractions     02-0419 02-419TK        500     400     200000.0
Fam_c1_1        F       Extractions     5107    5107TK  1475    447.5   660062.5
Fam_c10_1       F       Extractions     5132    5132TK  1555    547.6   851518.0
Fam_c100_1      M       Extractions     5843    5843TK  2605    398.6   1038353.0
Fam_c1000_1     F       Extractions     9913    9913TK  1900    398     756200.0
Fam_c1001_1     F       Extractions     9512    9512TK  1050    20      21000.0
```

So in this case I'd like my code to go through the list, have the first value of the list in the memory all the time. If it matches next lines first value it would do x.

Comment: .. and what is `index[0]`? It isn't shown in your code. Do you mean `line[0]`?

Comment: Maybe you can give some examples of what you're trying to do, because the question is unclear.

Comment: Yes I mean the first index after split, so in this case line[0]. By temp memory I mean is there a temporary memory where I can have this first index value "floating" all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd propose to use sth like this:

```
with open('filename') as f:

   def lineValue(line):
     parts = line.split('\t')
     return float(parts[5]) * float(parts[6])

   def lineKey(line):
     parts = line.split('\t')
     return parts[0]

   for match, lines in groupby(
       line for line in f if "Fam" in line and "TK" in line,
       lineKey):
     yield sum(lineValue(line) for line in lines)
```

This way it depends on the fact that all matching values are already following each other.  If this is not the case, `itertools.groupby()` won't help.  And of course, splitting the line twice isn't the most elegant solution.

If the matching lines won't follow each other, you will need to build a dict of answers, and then a `defaultdict` sound reasonable:

```
result = defaultdict(float)
with open('filename') as f:

   def lineValue(line):
     parts = line.split('\t')
     return float(parts[5]) * float(parts[6])

   def lineKey(line):
     parts = line.split('\t')
     return parts[0]

   for line in f:
     if "Fam" in line and "TK" in line:
       result[lineKey(line)] += lineValue(line)
```

And again, splitting the line just once would be a more elegant solution.

Comment: I have no idea what the OP is asking, but I'm pretty sure this doesn't answer it. There's not much point in trying to answer this unless the question is clarified.

Comment: I had the feeling that there were some issues in his code I could already address.  Maybe you are right that this won't help him go all the way.

Comment: `this` is not doing anything there currently. By matching `index[0]` I  was referring exactly what groupby does, but I was hoping that there is more elegant way of doing this so I could read/write/sum up on the fly and not creating huge lists.

Comment: `itertools.groupby()` just iterates and produces no lists.  I will add it to my answer …

Comment: Also edited my question so people would understand me better :)

Comment: Now using `groupby` and added a version using `defaultdict` in case the matching lines won't follow each other.